# Gauss-Markov theorem explanation (linear regression)

Tags: regression, matrix, gauss-markov-theorem

I have attatched an excerpt from my linear modelling lecture notes, this is the statement of the Gauss-Markov theorem, trouble is it goes into no more detail after this (not even explaining what the vector/matrix $l$ is supposed to be). Additionally what does 'the minimum variance linear unbiased estimator of the estimable function' mean? Can anyone shed some light on this explanation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $\ell$ is whatever you want it to be. That is, *if* you want to estimate some linear combination of the true coefficients $\beta$, the *same* linear combination of the estimated coefficients $\hat\beta$ is the minimum variance linear unbiased estimator.

1. Unbiased: the expected value of the estimator is the linear combination of the $\beta$ that you are trying to estimate
2. Linear: the estimator is a linear combination of the $Y$s
3. Minimum variance: out of all estimators that satisfy 1. and 2., the estimator has the smallest variance

Comment: What a great answer! Thank you for clearing that up.